# How to retrieve a field value on SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, html, model, sapui5

I'm starting on OPENUI5/SAPUI5 and I was trying to access the data for the controls i've implemented. For example:

`<Label text="Amount" />
<Input id="inputAmount" value="{Amount}" />
<Text id="lblCurrency" text="USD" >`

1. How to get the programatically values for inputAmount or lblCurrency?
2. Initially i'm using a mockup-server, how to get access to the odata model programatically? I'm using:

`console.log( this.getView().getModel().getJSON() );`

I can't get the structure, but i had deployed the data on the objects and actually is showed on screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get the control by it's id and then access it's value so in your code:

**Accessing the Text control in the controller**

```
sap.ui.getCore().byId("lblCurrency").getText()
```

**Accessing the Input value control in the controller**

```
sap.ui.getCore().byId("inputAmount").getValue()
```

The code above show how to access to value in the standard way. If you will use binding (binding is when you have a model which updates your view and if it's 2-way binding also your view updates you model) then in order to access to value you need to access access the model and extract it from there

example of binding and how to use it can be found here:

https://help.sap.com/saphelp_uiaddon10/helpdata/en/91/f0f3cd6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070/content.htm

**Update**

in order to get the data from the model you need to use the **getProperty** function under the model so your code should look some

```
oModel.getProperty("{PATH_TO_WHERE_THE_PROPERTY_IS_LOCATED",{OPTIONAL_CONTEXT}};
```

Comment: That's ok, it works. But some values from model aren't on controls. Is there any way to accessing the data from the odata destination model?

Comment: The problem with oModel.getProperty() is I can't find how to assign oModel variable to the Hana Destination oData. I use the destination in order to load data from oData on the controls, but I can't get a way to get access programatically directly.

Comment: The idea is to create oDataModel that will be initiate by your oData service document and then you bind entitysets from this oDataModel to your UI controls and when you do it UI5 core will execute the oData call to the service to get the data and then will display the data on your UI5 controls.